# Word VBA - CopyPaste Image-header in a new Document

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, ms-office, bookmarks

I've a function that copies a specified table into a new document, but i cant figure out how to export the header, which is an image, and set it as header for the document's pages.

The table is selected in base of the actual value of the combobox (ProjectsList.Value), which refers to
a bookmark and the table contained in it is  succesfly copy-pasted in a new document

For each pasted page, i want to copy the header too.

my function in which i would integrate the header part:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim Source As Document
Dim Target As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim tr As Range
Dim hRange As Word.Range

Set Source = ActiveDocument
Set Target = Documents.Add
Target.SaveAs FileName:=ProjectsList.Value

For Each tbl In Source.Bookmarks(ProjectsList.Value).Range.Tables
    Set tr = Target.Range
    tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    tr.FormattedText = tbl.Range.FormattedText
    tr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    tr.Text = vbCrLf
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Replicate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Source As Document, Target As Document
Dim Tbl As Table, HdFt As HeaderFooter, Rng As Range
Set Source = ActiveDocument: Set Target = Documents.Add
With Target
    For Each Tbl In Source.Bookmarks(ProjectsList.Value).Range.Tables
        Set Rng = .Range.Characters.Last
        Rng.FormattedText = Tbl.Range.FormattedText
        Rng.InsertAfter vbCr
    Next
    For Each HdFt In Source.Sections.First.Headers
        With HdFt
            Set Rng = Target.Sections.First.Headers(.Index).Range
            Rng.FormattedText = .Range.FormattedText
            Rng.Characters.Last.Delete
        End With
    Next
    .SaveAs FileName:=ProjectsList.Value
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```